# makefile setting different linker flags for different archtectures

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker

I want one make file to compile and link on windows (into mylib.dll) and at least two Linux architectures, i686 and armv61 (into mylib.so).

If I 'set' linker flags manually, my code compile / links ok.

But I want to set linker flags based upon certain ARC values, see snippet.

```
<code>
ARCH = "?"
ARCH = $(shell arch)
$(info ARCH  is [$(ARCH)])
LD_FLAGS = "?"
ifeq  "$(ARCH)" "i686"
LD_FLAGS = -shared -lSDL
endif
ifeq  "$(ARCH)" "armv61"
LD_FLAGS = -shared -lSDL -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
endif
$(info LD_FLAGS is [$(LD_FLAGS)])
</code>
```

On my i686 I get :

```
<code>
ARCH  is [i686]
LD_FLAGS is [-shared -lSDL]
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
</code>
```

On my armv61 I get :

```
<code>
ARCH  is [armv6l]
LD_FLAGS is ["?"]
... (error stuff!)
</code>
```

So ARCH is set ok but LD_FLAGS are not, I'm doing something stupid with the ifeq etc.

Any idea what the error is, how to fix the make file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a `1` instead of `l` (`armv6l` vs `armv61`)

Comment: Oops .... damn my old dog eyes, your right I just checked, looks like green on black needs an upgrade ... thanks